# I'm looking for an algorithm to find unknown patterns in a string

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, strings, substrings

I am trying to detect patterns in huge code bases.
I managed to filter the entire codebase into a tagged string,
as in:
ABACBABAABBCBABA

The result should be:
ABA *3
CBA *2

I'm trying to build / use an algorithm which will find ANY unknown repeating pattern inside the string. The length of the pattern, it's composition, and the number of repeats is unknow.

To be a pattern it must occur atleast twice. And have atleast 2 items.
Once I detect the patterns I can represent them back in their original context

I have tried iterating over each tag.
For each tag find the following tag in the string.
continue until adding a tag matches only one repeat - hence no more pattern.

I get lost in implemetation (in JS or Python) and I'm hoping there is a better way.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Can you specify more precisely what kinds of patterns you want to look for?  An example isn't a substitute for a specification of the problem.  Are you simply looking for repeated substrings that occur at least twice?  There are standard algorithms for finding the longest repeated substring; have you tried looking at them to see if they will meet your needs?  There are probably many algorithms; are you looking for the fastest, or the easiest to implement?  Do you have specific running time requirements?

Comment: Maybe you can look up the lempel ziv algorithm

Comment: "The result should be:" -- why? Which definition/metric of "good" did you use here? Why do you expect it to be applicable to more than this small example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple search in Python:

```
s = "ABACBABAABBCBABA"
d={}
for sublen in range(MINLEN,int(len(s)/MINCNT)):
    for i in range(0,len(s)-sublen):
        sub = s[i:i+sublen]
        cnt = s.count(sub)
        if cnt >= MINCNT and sub not in d:
             d[sub] = cnt
```

Where MINLEN is the minimum length of pattern you want to find and MINCNT is the minimum number of occurrences of that pattern. This runs in O(n^3) (nested for loop + .count()).

If you set MINCNT=2 and MINLEN=2 the result of running this is `d = {'CB': 2, 'BABA': 2, 'AB': 4, 'CBAB': 2, 'CBABA': 2, 'BAB': 2, 'BA': 5, 'ABA': 3, 'CBA': 2}`

These are all of the patterns that match your string given your description. Your question is a bit unclear in the example, if this is not what you are looking for let me know.

Comment: Thanks!
Worked perfectly.
I now need to tune it to give the longest pattern without internal repeats,
for instance for ABCDABCDABCDABCD

I need the result to be:
ABCD 
and not ABCDABCD or AB, BC, CD, DA

But the definition for this is not yet clear in my head so I can't expect to write the algorithm just yet.
You put me on a good start. Merci

Answer (score 5):

Construct the [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) of your string, which takes time linear in the length of the string (assuming a finite alphabet). Every inner node represents a repeat, their respective descendant leaves encode the positions.

Answer (score 2):

What you need looks exactly like an LZ77 algorithm. It has many possible implementations. In particular, you can perform [suffix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) on input data (current algorithms are so efficient that they can sort 10 megabytes in less than a second), and get index into your text, sorted on full string being pointed. One particular fast implementation is https://github.com/y-256/libdivsufsort - I think it should be more efficient and easier to use than the suffix tree.

Answer (score 1):

I am put this just in case if someone else is interested with this topic. I find the following work easy to understand and implement for pattern discovery in string.

E. Keogh, J. Lin and A. Fu (2005). HOT SAX: Efficiently Finding the Most Unusual Time Series Subsequence. In Proc. of the 5th IEEE International Conference on Data Mining (ICDM 2005), pp. 226 - 233., Houston, Texas, Nov 27-30, 2005.

The paper is available here. [https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/HOT%20SAX%20%20long-ver.pdf](https://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Eeamonn/HOT%20SAX%20%20long-ver.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, what you're asking is pretty much the opposite of the question "How truly random a string is?".
There's a huge literature on this in Cryptography and specifically random and pseudorandom generators, you can use statistical tests and tools to recognize recurring patterns.
But first you must have a clear vision on how to sort the significance of these patterns, I recommend defining a utility function u(n, r) in which n is the length of the pattern and r is it's repetition.